# Passing td value to modal html php

Tags: php, html, css, modal-dialog

```
 <td value="541">123</td>
 <td value="542">456</td>



 $("#table td").click(function(){  
 var value=$(this).html();
 alert(value);              
 });
```

i want to pass the td value 541 to modal
but when i click I only get the value 123

Comment: Well, you're getting the html contents of the td with html()...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `value` is not a valid attribute for a `td` tag, you should use `data-*` attributes to store custom data.

> The data-* attributes gives us the ability to embed custom data attributes on all HTML elements.

See docs: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

```js
$("#table td").click(function(){  
  var value=$(this).data("value");
  alert(value);              
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td data-value="541">123</td>
    <td data-value="542">456</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

value isn't really used on the td element.  However, you can always grab its value like this:

```
$("#table td").click(function(){  
  var value=$(this).attr("value");
  alert(value);              
});
```

Comment: Thanks how can i commend you!